# Django: render only last part of image url in template

Tags: django

I've a model that has an image field as attribute. I need to render the attributes of this model in my template, but specifically the image.url atribute.

Right now, I can render it as:

```
/media/images/floral.jpg
```

However, I'd like to only render the last part:

```
floral.jpg
```

So I'm using this in my template:

```
{{ cart_item.image.url }}
```

**What can I do to only render the last part of the image url?**

```
class SizeQuantity(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TAMANIOS)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CANTIDADES)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.size
```

**view.py**

```
def cart_detail(request, total = 0, counter = 0, cart_items = None):
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id = _cart_id(request))
        cart_items =  SizeQuantity.objects.filter(cart = cart)

    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass

    return render(request, 'cart.html', dict(cart_items = cart_items, total = total, counter = counter))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this property to the SizeQuantity model:

```
@property
def image_filename(self):
    return self.image.url.split('/')[-1]
```

The in your template call it as `{{ cart_item.image_filename }}`.